# Enable/Disable jQuery FilterTable On Case-By-Case Basis

Tags: jquery

Is there any way to tell FilterTable to ignore certain tables in their entirety?

A site I've inherited uses [FilterTable](http://sunnywalker.github.io/jQuery.FilterTable/) on tables that display data; this adds a nice "Search this table" input at the top of each table to filter the table data based on what's typed in the search input. However, this same site also sometimes uses tables for page layout so the "Search this table" input is appearing at the top of **every** table, whether the table is being used for data or for layout.

FilterTable has a minRows=X option which tells it whether or not to display the search input if the table has at least X rows. Problem is that some of the layout tables have more than X rows... Setting X=100 (for example) would prevent the search input from appearing above the layout tables but would also prevent it from appearing above data tables unless there were at least 100 rows of data.

Re-doing the numerous layout tables as divs would solve this problem but would be a huge undertaking.

Answer (score 0):

Well, duh. FilterTable was being called in a site-wide scripts file. I hard-coded an exclusion for the particular pages that use tables but don't need FilterTable implemented.